# How to correctly check if a result set is ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I want to check if my result set is of type `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`

for example my models are as follows

```
class Dashboard < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :organisations
end
```

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :dashboards
end
```

When i do `organisation.dashboards` i want to check if its `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`

but something like the below does not work.

```
expect(organisation.dashboards).to be(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
```

Any help in this would be really great, Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to test that a `CollectionProxy` is returned? I would argue that you are testing Rails internals here. What do you try to archieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use rspec [Type matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers) here

> expect(obj).to be_kind_of(type): calls obj.kind_of?(type), which returns true if type is in obj's class hierarchy or is a module and is included in a class in obj's class hierarchy.

```rb
expect(organisation.dashboards).to be_kind_of(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
```

OR

```rb
expect(organisation.dashboards).to be_a_kind_of(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
```

OR

```rb
expect(organisation.dashboards).to be_a(ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy)
```